# Can't install condor on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, condor

I have been trying to install condor on my centos virtual machine but keep getting the following errors:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: condor-classads-8.5.5-1.el6.x86_64 (htcondor-development)
           Requires: libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: condor-8.5.5-1.el6.x86_64 (htcondor-development)
           Requires: ecryptfs-utils
Error: Package: condor-8.5.5-1.el6.x86_64 (htcondor-development)
           Requires: libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I looked around online and tried all the suggestions but nothing's worked. I did the next logical thing and tried to install those packages but doing `yum install ecryptfs-utils` gave me "Nothing to do," message. Same with libpcre.so.0() I'm a beginner with Linux so I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. Help appreciated.

Comment: ? How are you trying to install condor into CentOS ? Please edit your post to include the install command ... and the exact CentOS version, like CentOS 6.8 - 64bits. -

Comment: P.S. condor-classads-8.5.5-1.el6.x86_64 is from development / upcoming http://repo.opensciencegrid.org/osg/upcoming/el6/development/x86_64/ -

Comment: did you ever get this done?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and this was happening because yum was trying to install different version of condor. I was running centos 6.6, but yum was trying to install centos 7 (rhel 7) version. The reason for this was, by mistake, I initially downloaded and setup the rhel7 repo details of condor, and results got cached.

The solution is to clear yum cache (`yum clean all`), download the correct condor repo for your CentOS version/arch (use `rpm -q centos-release` to find this out), and then install (`yum install condor-all`).

Answer (score 0):

Get condor from the [official location](https://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/downloads/?state=select_from_mirror_page&version=8.5.6&mirror=UW%20Madison&optional_organization_url=http://). It has all the binaries it needs.